# Count empty or not empty TD with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Usually `input` and `textarea` can be checkt and counted by its selector and length.

e.g. Counting empty inputs and textareas:

```
$('input[value=""]').length;

$('textarea[value=""]').length;
```

How this can be done with a Table ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The count should be 2. I know I could use a `$.each(...)` but I would prefere a simple `$(selector).length` solution.

EDIT: corrected the topic a bit to get this small confusion away, sorry! :D

Comment: The title asks about "not empty" elements, while your example gets empty elements. Which are you looking for?

Comment: either :empty or .filter or .map... The examples are not coherent with the question, though.

Comment: beware that any whitespace inside a tag will not be considered `:empty` ... example `<td> </td>` won't be selected as `:empty`

Comment: @charlietfl thats ok. Its my source and even there is something in the table or its really empty. The table is build by a ajax-request and data is trimmed so this will never be a problem. But thanks for that hint.

Comment: just worth knowing...can be frustrating on page where line breaks or other space occurs and `:empty` doesn't do what you think it should

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` selector:

```js
console.log($('table td:empty').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As @Pointy mentions, you can invert the behaviour using `:not()` if you want to select `td` elements that do have some content:

```
$('table td:not(:empty)').length
```

Comment: That would work, although the OP says `Counting empty inputs and textareas:` and the code is doing the same with inputs by empty value.

Comment: I agree, the OP is confusing. It's one or the other :)

Comment: sorry for this confusion. :) In the end its not nessesary if its count on empty or filled. But that's what i was looking for. Thx

Comment: sorry if I am doing something wrong but using `console.log($('table td:not(:empty)').length)` with the above example does not output anything in console @Pointy

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam there may be an error in your logic somewhere then, as it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/y044mtzo/

Comment: it was actually that the white-spaces in the `td` actually that was not allowing any of the `td` to be selected as empty, sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a caveat to be aware of. You can get around it, if needed, by using `filter()` and calling `trim()` the current `text()` value of the element

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `:empty` pseudo selector to check whether a DOM element contains data or not.

```
$("td:empty").length
```

This will give you empty td count

If you want to count the non empty td elements then:

```
$("td:not(:empty)").length
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
 $('td:not(empty)')
```